# Ruby Blocks and Yield

Tags: ruby

What is the

```
yield self if block
```

does it only mean if there was a block attached to the initiation method it would be called at the end?

```
def initialize options = {}, &block

  @type = self.class.to_s.split('::').last.downcase.to_sym
  @version = options.delete(:version) || 1.0
  @language = options.delete(:language) || :en
  @query = options.delete(:query)
  @api_key = options.delete(:key) || :notsupplied
  @options = options
  raise Error, 'Do not initialize Google::Search; Use a subclass such as  Google::Search::Web' if @type == :search
  yield self if block
```

Comment: Where is that code from? It's not a good idea to capture the block with `&block` needlessly (instead use `block_given?`). I also hate methods that don't leave my options intact... http://blog.marc-andre.ca/2009/03/leave-my-options-alone.html

Comment: I got the code from the official google search gem from Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, pretty much. So you can do something like:

```
Google::Search::Web.new do |search|
  # ...
end
```

(Though, from a software design point of view, running user-specified code in a constructor always seemed strange to me. A better approach is what `File` and `IO` do, where `open` does pretty much the same thing as `new`, except that `open` runs the passed-in block, whereas `new` does not.)

Answer (score 2):

When you write a method like this:

```
def foo( a, b, &c )
  ...
end
```

Then the variable `c` is set to a Proc instance if you pass a block to the method, or set to `nil` if you don't pass a block. Because `nil` is a non-truth value, the method you cite is testing to see if a block was passed to decide whether to yield or not.

As @MarcAndréLafortune says, the better code is: `yield if block_given?`. The only times you want to capture a block (that I can think of) are:

1. In order to save it into an instance variable for use later:

   - e.g. `@foo = c` and then later either invoke it and pass in values (`@foo[ 42 ]`), or pass it as a block to another method `my_array.select(&@foo)`.
2. Or, pass it along directly as a block to other methods called by your method:

   - e.g. `@my_array = initial_values.select(&c)`